# How to trigger boot.scr creation in Petalinux v2021.1?

Tags: xilinx, u-boot, petalinux

Recently, I'm facing problems related to mismatches between the actual image offsets in my QSPI flash and the offsets that are used in U-Boot via `boot.scr`. I saw that the offsets that are used in `boot.scr` can be updated using `petalinux-config` menu. ***(u-boot Configuration → u-boot script configuration → QSPI/OSPI image offsets)***

However, even if I update the given offsets, the `boot.scr` file doesn't get affected. So, what is the way of triggering the recreation of `boot.scr` of U-Boot?

I've tried clearing the U-Boot build by calling `petalinux-build -c u-boot -x distclean`, and it didn't work. I don't want to rebuild the whole project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the image offset values as you described will trigger the boot.scr file to update the next time you run `petalinux-build`.

You can also [modify the boot.scr file directly](https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/749142017/Using+Distro+Boot+With+Xilinx+U-Boot#Using-the-boot.scr-Method).